# Div doesn't hide after showing it with jquery

Tags: jquery, class, hide, show

I would like to show and hide a div. Showing the div after clicking a span is no problem, but when I wan't to hide it again it doesn't work.

```
$('#first-search').click(function(){
    $('#first-search').find('.popup-search').addClass('show');
});

$('#submit-product').click(function(){
    $('.popup-search').removeClass('show');
    $('#first-search').find('.answer').text('Rolstoel');
});
```

This is the jQuery script. The second line where the class 'answer' gets another text is working. The removal of the class assigned to popup-search isn't working.

HTML

```
<div id="first-search">
                Ik ben op zoek naar een <span class="answer">jouw antwoord</span>
                <div class="popup-search">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="product" placeholder="Welk product zoek je?"> 
                        <div id="submit-product">Bevestigen</div>                       
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
#first-search{
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
    position:relative;
}

.answer{
    border-bottom:1px dotted #333;
    color:#333;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.popup-search{
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    bottom: -122px;
    right: 320px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display:none;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 12px #879e30;
}

.show{
    display:block;
}     

#submit-product{
    padding: 6px 10px;
    width: 206px;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #b3d33a;
    color: #404041;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    font-size:12px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: add a jsfiddle if you like help with that :)

Comment: `$('.popup-search').hide()` use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because a click in `#submit-product` is also a click in `#first-search`, so a click into it fires both callback functions. A fix would be to save the hover state of `#submit-product`. Only if it is **not** hovered, add the class `show` to the `.popup-search`.

Something like this should do the job (not tested):

```
var submit_product_hovered = false;
$('#first-search').click(function() {
  if(!submit_product_hovered) {
    $('#first-search').find('.popup-search').addClass('show');
  }
});
$('#submit-product').click(function() {
  $('.popup-search').removeClass('show');
  $('#first-search').find('.answer').text('Rolstoel');
});
$('#submit-product').mouseover(function() {
  submit_product_hovered = true;
}
$('#submit-product').mouseleave(function() {
  submit_product_hovered = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// try to inlude css  display none

```
.popup-search{
        position: absolute;
        width: 250px;
        bottom: -122px;
        right: 320px;
        z-index: 100;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        display:none;
        box-shadow: 0 7px 12px #879e30;
       display:none;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies.
Finally I decided to trigger the answer class instead of the parent div:

```
$('.answer').click(function(){
        $(this).next().removeClass('hide');
    });

    $('#submit-product,#submit-location,#submit-radius').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('hide');
        var filledtext = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.answer').text(filledtext);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add "hide" extra.

$('#submit-product').click(function(){

```
$('.popup-search').removeClass('show').hide();

$('#first-search').find('.answer').text('Rolstoel');
```

});